# Select a (non-indexed) column based on text content of a cell in a python/pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**TL:DR - how do I create a dataframe/series from one or more columns in an existing non-indexed dataframe based on the column(s) containing a specific piece of text?**

Relatively new to Python and data analysis and (this is my first time posting a question on Stack Overflow but I've been hunting for an answer for a long time (and used to code regularly) and not having any success.

I have a dataframe import from an Excel file that doesn't have named/indexed columns. I am trying to successfully extract data from nearly 2000 of these files which all have slightly different columns of data (of course - why make it simple... or follow a template... or simply use something other than poorly formatted Excel spreadsheets...).

The original dataframe (from a poorly structured XLS file) looks a bit like this:

```
0                                       NaN             RIGHT      NaN   
1                                      Date              UCVA      Sph   
2                       2007-01-13 00:00:00              6/38  [-2.00]   
3                       2009-11-05 00:00:00               6/9      NaN   
4                       2009-11-18 00:00:00              6/12      NaN   
5                       2009-12-14 00:00:00               6/9  [-1.25]   
6                       2018-04-24 00:00:00           worn CL  [-5.50]   

           3     4      5                 6     7     8        9   \
0         NaN   NaN    NaN               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   
1         Cyl  Axis  BSCVA  Pentacam remarks    K1    K2  K2 back   
2     [-2.75]    65    6/9               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   
3         NaN   NaN    NaN               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   
4         NaN   NaN    6/5         Pentacam     46  43.9     -6.6   
5     [-5.75]    60  6/6-1               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   
6     [+7.00}   170  6/7.5               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   

           ...              17                18    19    20       21     22  \
0          ...             NaN               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN   
1          ...           BSCVA  Pentacam remarks    K1    K2  K2 back  K max   
2          ...             6/5               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN   
3          ...             NaN               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN   
4          ...             NaN          Pentacam  44.3  43.7     -6.2   45.5   
5          ...           6/4-4               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN   
6          ...             6/5               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN
```

I want to extract a set of dataframes/series that I can then combine back together to get a 'tidy' dataframe e.g.:

```
1                                      Date              R-UCVA      R-Sph   
2                       2007-01-13 00:00:00              6/38  [-2.00]   
3                       2009-11-05 00:00:00               6/9      NaN   
4                       2009-11-18 00:00:00              6/12      NaN   
5                       2009-12-14 00:00:00               6/9  [-1.25]   
6                       2018-04-24 00:00:00           worn CL  [-5.50]   

1       R-Cyl R-Axis R-BSCVA  R-Penta          R-K1   R-K2  R-K2 back   
2     [-2.75]    65    6/9               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   
3         NaN   NaN    NaN               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   
4         NaN   NaN    6/5         Pentacam     46  43.9     -6.6   
5     [-5.75]    60  6/6-1               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN   
6     [+7.00}   170  6/7.5               NaN   NaN   NaN      NaN
```

etc. etc. so I'm trying to write some code that will pull a series of columns that I define by looking for the words "Date" or "UCVA" etc. etc. Then I plan to stitch them back together into a single dataframe with patient identifier as an extra column. And then cycle through all the XLS files, appending the whole lot to a single CSV file that I can then do useful stuff on (like put into an Access Database -  yes, I know, but it has to be easy to use and already installed on an NHS computer - and statistical analysis).

Any suggestions? I hope that's enough information.

Thanks very much in advance.

Kind regards
Vicky

Comment: Do I understand the question correctly: you want to extract a set of columns from a Dataframe into a new Dataframe and then merge a large number of Dataframes together? Do you want to merge them on a column or do you want to stack them?

Comment: It looks like a good place to start is to use the `header` and `skiprows` parameters when you read in your file, assuming each is formatted similarly. That will get your columns indexed, and you can select the ones you want from there

Answer (score 0):

Here a something that will hopefully get you started. 
I have prepared a `text.xlsx` file:
[image: Excel file]
and I can read it as follows

```
    path = 'text.xlsx'

    df = pd.read_excel(path, header=[0,1])

    # Deal with two levels of headers, here I just join them together crudely 
    df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda h: '  '.join(h))

    # Slight hack because I messed with the column names
    # I create two dataframes, one with the first column, one with the second column
    df1 = df[[df.columns[0],df.columns[1]]]
    df2 = df[[df.columns[0], df.columns[2]]]

    # Stacking them on top of each other
    result = pd.concat([df1, df2])
    print(result)

    #Merging them on the Date column
    result = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on=df1.columns[0])
    print(result)
```

This gives the output

```
  RIGHT  Sph RIGHT  UCVA       Unnamed: 0_level_0  Date
0        NaN              6/38      2007-01-13 00:00:00
1        NaN              6/37      2009-11-05 00:00:00
2        NaN              9/56      2009-11-18 00:00:00
0    [-2.00]               NaN      2007-01-13 00:00:00
1        NaN               NaN      2009-11-05 00:00:00
2        NaN               NaN      2009-11-18 00:00:00
```

and

```
  Unnamed: 0_level_0  Date RIGHT  UCVA       RIGHT  Sph
0      2007-01-13 00:00:00              6/38    [-2.00]
1      2009-11-05 00:00:00              6/37        NaN
2      2009-11-18 00:00:00              9/56        NaN
```

*Some pointers:*
How to merger two header rows? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259735/how-to-merge-a-multirows-header-of-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-single-cell-header) question and answer.

How to select pandas columns conditionally? See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558071/selecting-columns-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-columns-conditions) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe)

How to merge dataframes? There is a very good guide in the pandas [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)